# arrays with user input and prints out in reverse

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x

I'm trying to write a program that takes an array of size N as input and gives the output as an array in the reverse order.

E.g.

```
3
123
```

should produce 321

```
or 4
   1210
```

should produce 0121.

My current code:

```
num_array = [] 
num = input()
print()
for i in range(int(num)): 
    n = input()
    num_array.append(int(n))
print(num_array[::-1])
```

but I get the error `ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: ''` on the line `num_array.append(int(n))`. Not sure what's wrong with it.

Comment: -1, this is a common problem if correct input is not passed, 100 of SO questions are there to solve and debug this. If this still didn't solved your problem, your should show input and complete error your are getting - not a specific line!

Comment: I've already shown the correct input needed and already shown you the output I get ?

Comment: The correct input, is the input I enter when I'm asked for an input

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What I changed:

1. I added a prompt for the user (it helped me when testing and I'm sure it will help you too).
2. I added a check to make sure the user enters a valid, numeric string (before we convert it using `int`.
3. Addressing your specific concern:

   - Make sure you are entering your data by using `1{enter}2{enter}3{enter}`.  Because you have it shown as `123` and `1 2 3`.
   - If you want to be able to enter data like `123`, I can help you with that; just comment.

## Code

```
num_array = [] 
num = input("Please enter number of elements: ")
print('')
for i in range(int(num)): 
    n = input(f"Element[i]: ")
    if not n.isnumeric():
        print("Please enter an integer")
        raise "You failed to enter an integer"
    num_array.append(int(n))
print(num_array[::-1])
```

## If you want to use spaces

```
num_array = ''.join(input("Please enter your data: ").split())[::-1]
print(num_array)
```

Program running:

```
Input<< Please enter your data: 5 2 1 3
Output>> 3125
```

## If you want to use no spaces

```
num_array = input(f"Please enter your data: ")[::-1]
print(num_array)
```

Program running:

```
Input<< Please enter your data: 5123
Output>> 3215
```

## Noob Editor's explanation

(Included so I take up 90% of the total page space used).

Existing issue as per terminal dump :

```
In [6]: %cpaste
Pasting code; enter '--' alone on the line to stop or use Ctrl-D.
:def abc():
    num_array = [] 
    num = input()
    print()
    for i in range(int(num)): 
        n = input()
        num_array.append(int(n))
    print(num_array[::-1])       
:--

In [7]: abc()
2

12                  // this is where enter is pressed

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-7-79c8afb7007d> in <module>()
----> 1 abc()

<ipython-input-6-f0dc94278ce8> in abc()
      5     for i in range(int(num)):
      6         n = input()
----> 7         num_array.append(int(n))
      8     print(num_arra)

ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: ''

In [8]:
```

---- correct implementaion ---

```
In [9]: def abc():
   ...:     num_array = [] 
   ...:     num = input()
   ...:     print()
   ...:     for i in range(int(num)): 
   ...:         n = input()
   ...:         num_array.append(int(n))
   ...:     print(num_array[::-1])
   ...:     

In [10]: abc()
2

1                   //input in separate lines
2
[2, 1]

In [11]:
```

Comment: Yeah i want it to enter data like 123

Comment: too lazy to type and answer, used yours as base, hope you dont mind! :)

Comment: @M.Jones  If you want to use no spaces, refer to the section titled **If you want to use no spaces**.

Comment: What do i replace the num_array = input line with ?

Comment: @NoobEditor Flawless, as usual.  I would upvote myself if I could.

Comment: @M.Jones That implementation, coincidentally, is really easy to implement. You can use `num_array = input(f"Please enter your data: ")[::-1]`.  You are using a string and then reversing the input.  I suppose that `num_array` isn't a very good name for it now, though.

Answer (score 1):

You are casting `n` to int, so I suppose you have in your input something that is not a number.

In order to fix it you may drop the casting. `num_array.append(n)` and that should be all (Or make sure that the input consist with numbers only).

Comment: When I take it out, it takes the output as a string

Comment: @M.Jones , True, But if you cast to int, you have to insert numbers only. You got the literal error as you inserted as input something that is not a number.

Comment: @M.Jones : what is the input you are giving?

Comment: @NoobEditor I'm inputting exactly what I showed above. 3 which specifies the array size, then followed by 1 2 3 which should then be outputed as 3 2 1

Comment: @omri_saadon that's weird because I'm only entering numbers

Comment: @M.Jones , You can't insert '1 2 3' as input. You run in a loop (in your case three iterations), you need to insert 1 and then press enter, than 2 than press enter, than 3 and enter. this would work.

Comment: @M.Jones : got your error... you are passing 123 and then press `enter`. `enter` is getting parsed as input and invalid literal.This is more of a logical error than code issue!

Comment: Because When i press enter to run it , it just skips to the next line. Then I press enter again and it gives me that literal error

Comment: @M.Jones :  honest suggestion ,read basics of python first  :)  || hint for what you asked : `a = "123"` then 

`for i in a: print(i)`
    ...:     
1
2
3

Answer (score 0):

It is not exactly clear, what your intended use of the first input is. Do you want to input the total length of your array, which is the total number of elements it contains or do you want to specify the length of your input?

If you want to specify the total length of your array, which is '1' for both inputs '123' and '1210' (since you input a single string), then your exception was probably caused by another empty input (pressing return), which could not be translated into an integer.

If you want to know the length of your input, e.g. '4' for the input '1210' or '3' for the input '123', you can get that with `len(n)` (where `n = input()`)

Assuming you tried to specify the length of the input number (which is not necessary), code that would work with your examples could look like:

```
num_array = list(input())
print(''.join(map(str, (num_array[::-1]))))
```

or with use of [reversed](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0322/):

```
num_array = list(input())
print(''.join(map(str, reversed(num_array))))
```